# По разному отображаются шрифты(сделал разные типы шрифтов)

Tags: css, шрифты

Привет!
Вот так я подключил шрифт:

```
.text{
    font-size: 50px ;
    font-family: "OpenSans";
}


@font-face {

        font-family: "OpenSans";
        src: url("fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot");
        src: url("fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
        src: url("fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
```

Картинка с оперы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка с MicrosoftEdge

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я неправильно подключил шрифты что в опере такие рубци а в едже се гладенько?

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит гнаться за одинаковым отображением шрифтов во всех браузерах, этого никогда не получится сделать из-за разной работы движков, касается это и тех же `box-shadow`, `text-shadow` и некоторых `transform`. Это больше относится к вопросу кроссбраузерности. Можешь посмотреть на канале html academy очень хороший шорт по этому поводу - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFZWHLjNXdI